# Proof of Weierstrass-Stone theorem

Tags: real-analysis

let $\mathscr{A}$ be an algebra of real continuous functions on a compact set $K$.  $\mathscr{B}$ is the uniform closure of $\mathscr{A}$.

prove:  if $f \in \mathscr{B}$, then $|f| \in \mathscr{B}$.

I write the following proof:

$f \in \mathscr{B}$, then there exists the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converge to $f$ uniformly. According to the definition,  for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ for $\forall n \ge N$ and $x \in K$, we have 
\begin{equation}
||f_n| - |f|| \le |f_n - f| < \epsilon.
\end{equation}
So $|f_n|$ converge to $|f|$ uniformly. All $f_n$ are the continuous real function and $|x|$ is the continuous function, then $|f_n| \in \mathscr{A}$. Finally, we obtain $|f| \in \mathscr{B}$.

I wonder whether the proof is correct or not. If incorrect, where is the wrong?

Comment: Your reason for $|f_n| \in \mathscr{A}$ seems wrong. In fact this should not be true for a general algebra $\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: $f^2$ is in the algebra. Now consider polynomials converging uniformly to $\sqrt{x}$ and compose them with $f^2$.

Comment: I see where is the wrong.  $\mathscr{A}$ is defined on a set of real continuous functions on a compact set. Although $f_n$ is a real continuous functions on the compact set, it may not belong to the algebra $\mathscr{A}$. Thank you!

Comment: That is not the reason. $\mathscr{B}$ is the closure of $\mathscr{A}$, so you can assume that there is $f_n$ in $\mathscr{A}$ converging to $f$. The problem is in assuming $|f_n|$ is in $\mathscr{A}$ too. This last is pretty much the same as what you need to prove.

Comment: This is why you need to play with the operations you are allowed to do inside $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$, i.e. multiplying functions of $\mathscr{A}$, multiplying functions in $\mathscr{A}$ by real numbers, adding functions of $\mathscr{A}$, and taking uniform limits. The first operations allow you to take a function and compose it with a polynomial.  $1+f^2-3f^5+f^6$. The key is then to get the function absolute value $|\cdot|$ as a uniform limit of polynomials.